# adhoc - The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I had an adhoc problem, based on stackoverflow posts, I created new Certificate, and provisioning profiles, Removed all certificate and profiles from my Device and also PC,
Rest all of them, check UDID .. but still I have an error: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements,

test it with both iTunes and xcode
(0xE8008016)

Any comment, answer, feedback would be appropriated. 
Thanks in advanced.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The entitlements control things like whether you are allowed to attach a debugger to the app when it is running.

For App Store/Ad Hoc/Enterprise distribution cert/profiles, you are not allowed to attach debuggers.  If the entitlements settings or file say yes to the debugger, then the signing will fail like this.

If you need to attach the debugger, then sign with a developer provisioning profile.

Comment: so you mean if it is enabled and I disable it, It will be work??

Comment: Correct. The things in the entitlements settings or file must match what is allowed by the profile.  If get-task-allow can be YES for developer profiles, but must be NO for ad hoc or enterprise.

Comment: The entitlements file is specified in the target's "Build Settings". (Just search for "entitlements".  Then check the contents of the file for that target and configuration.